# Does an increase in Mach number lead to a decrease in Total Pressure Recovery (TPR) for supersonic inlets?

Tags: engine-design, supersonic, inlet, fluid-dynamics

I am curious if the total pressure recover for supersonic inlets, in general, decrease for an increase in Mach number.